# React and rss-parser yields Module not found

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rss

I'm trying to use `rss-parser` in my react app.
After installing the library, I implemented the following:

```
import Parser from 'rss-parser';

let parser = new Parser();

(async () => {

        let feed = await parser.parseURL('https://www.reddit.com/.rss');
        console.log(feed.title);

        feed.items.forEach(item => {
            console.log(item.title + ':' + item.link)
        });

})();
```

This throws the following error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/rss-parser/lib/parser.js 3:13-28

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in '\node_modules\rss-parser\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "http": require.resolve("stream-http") }'
    - install 'stream-http'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "http": false }
```

Where should I set the resolve.fallback info ?

Comment: why don't you just Add a polyfill for the 'http' module? Sorry, the answer to your question will be in webpack configuration.

Comment: I installed the packages timers-browserify , stream-browserify and url to add polyfill, but I cannot find webpack.config.js file

Comment: [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76742015/16298054) an answer that deals with similar issue. Though in your case it will be 'http' module instead of "path".